# Handle generation of non-identity primary key

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-4, primary-key

We currently have tables which don't have a identity for primary key. It would be too costly to change that because of interoperability.

I'm thinking about handling ObjectContext's SavingChanges event to set its values.

*(pseudocode)*

```
void SavingChanges(context)
{
    foreach (var entity in context)
    {
        if (entity.HasIdentity) continue;

        entity.PrimaryKey = GetNextPrimaryKey(entity.Type);
    }
}
```

I can only think of using a separate connection to accomplish this. And yes, GetNextPrimaryKey would be otimized to reduce the number of roundtrips, but I guess it was suficient to explain the overall idea.

Would it work? Should I try something different?

Comment: I think I should do a spike :)

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon the logic within the method GetNextPrimaryKey.

If your method is executed in multiple threads then you will have chances of same key being assigned to multiple objects.

Buti if your GetNextPrimaryKey advances your key and returns always a new key, regardless of whether it is used or not, then there is no problem.

But if your logic is simply to find out last used key and do key + 1, then in multithreaded situations or web applications, you will have conflicts.

Best would be to use some sort of Stored Procedure and return a new key always from SP, so there will not be any issue in case of parallel execution of GetNextPrimaryKey.